# Twitter search API response?

Tags: twitter, sttwitterapi

I am unable to understand, why **"retweeted": false**, even though **"retweet_count": 2**? Or does the **retweeted** point to something else?

Example API response:

```
  "retweet_count": 2,
  "retweeted": false,
  "retweeted_status": {
    "contributors": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "created_at": "Wed Sep 26 10:47:11 +0000 2018",
    "display_text_range": [
      0,
      90
    ],
    "entities": {
      "hashtags": [
        {
          "indices": [
            83,
            90
          ],
          "text": "ESMO18"
        }
      ],
      "symbols": [],
      "urls": [],
      "user_mentions": [
        {
          "id": 69232855,
          "id_str": "69232855",
          "indices": [
            12,
            19
          ],
          "name": "ESMO - Eur. Oncology",
          "screen_name": "myESMO"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Complete response: https://pastebin.com/QpQKb7ZM

Comment: This is clearly documented in twitter API documentation: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html#tweet-dictionary
Thanks for doing some research before asking in forums.

Comment: Yes, it is there. Seems like i missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is confusing - let me explain.

The `retweeted` property is whether the authenticating user has retweeted that specific tweet.

So if you retweeted me, then looked at that tweet, you would see `"retweeted": true,`

It really should be called something like `has_authenticating_user_retweeted_this` :-)